# Is using extract($_POST) insecure?

Tags: php, security

Is using `extract($_POST)` insecure? If yes then what can I do about this?

Comment: The question is really: why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: Evert, I just wanted to save time and code by using extract() instead of repeating $_POST[] a lot of times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is. It is the same thing that register_globals was. It means that if someone inject a value with the name "my_name" the variable "my_name" would exist. And if it exists, it can bring some garbage or security issue in your script if somewhere you use the variable `$my_name`

Answer (score 5):

From the php documentation:

> Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET, $_FILES, etc.). If you do, for example if you want to run old code that relies on register_globals temporarily, make sure you use one of the non-overwriting extract_type values such as EXTR_SKIP and be aware that you should extract in the same order that's defined in variables_order within the php.ini.

The recommended practice is to use `$_POST[<varname>]` directly, so that users of your site can not set variables that should be 'safe'

Answer (score 1):

It is always better simply read values from `$_POST`and do something with them instead of just exposing them as variables and risking overriding some of yours...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is insecure. Any one can override your local variables (for example `$password` or `$access_level`).

I recommend declaring and assigning your *own* local variables like this:

```
$var1 = isset($_POST['field_1'])?$_POST['field_1']:null;
$var2 = isset($_POST['field_2'])?$_POST['field_2']:null;
$var3 = isset($_POST['field_3'])?$_POST['field_3']:null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `extract($_POST)` is insecure, as others have stated. You asked what you could do about making `extract($_POST)` secure, specifically to avoid constantly referencing the `$_POST` array.

### The Literal Answer

You asked about using `extract($_POST)` securely. It is *somewhat* safe to use as the first line of your script, before any local variables have been defined, **or** with `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` and a prefix. In both cases however, you are making a risky gamble, that you will never accidentally introduce a security hole via typo *anywhere* in that variable scope. Global scope is exceptionally difficult to verify. Because all programmers make typos and the inconvenience is minimal, most programmers ***strongly*** encourage never `extract()`ing untrusted content, regardless of limited scope, prefixes, etc.

### The Correct Answer

`$_POST`ed data is untrusted and insecure. You never know what it might contain - or if it will even be set. It is useful to think of `$_POST` as "tainted" data which must be "cleaned" before assigning it to a local variable. As a result, you should be able to minimize your typing of "`$_POST`" by validating the input as you assign it to local variables. PHP 5.2 and up make this easier with the `filter_input()` and `filter_var()` functions with the validation filters.

As an aside, you should always *validate* your inputs and *sanitize* your outputs. If you instead sanitize your inputs you can run into problems displaying them in different contexts (ie, a non-HTML logger, printing to a terminal). If you don't sanitize your outputs, you run into XSS, SQL Injection, etc.

The rule of thumb encouraged by this mindset is to treat all data entering your system from another you don't control as "tainted", untrustworthy - you probably don't control the system running the web browser, unless developing for a LAN. Further, "defense in depth" encourages treating even trusted systems as compromisable (it happens), making this most generally best practices for programmers.