# Convert array element to variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Given,

```
$required_fields = array('name', 'location', 'email');                               
foreach ($required_fields as $fieldname) {
    if (isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || !empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {      


        }
```

Now in the if statement, I need something like

```
$fieldname = $_POST[$fieldname];
```

So that i get

$name = "name", $location = "location" and $email = "email"

I tried $fieldname = $_POST[$fieldname] But it don't work. How can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do it like this,

```
$$fieldname = $_POST[$fieldname];
```

This `$$` notation is called [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 3):

you could use `extract` [function](http://php.net/extract) for this. To filter array you can use `array_diff`  [function](http://php.net/array_diff)

Comment: could be also useful to take a look to - [Is using extract($_POST) insecure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907358/is-using-extract-post-insecure/11907417)

Comment: there's a possibility that `extract()` will overwrite your existing variables with new ones and that's debugging hell

Comment: @ianace Assigning variables like in question is a debugging hell.

Answer (score 1):

```
$required_fields = array('name', 'location', 'email');
extract(array_intersect_keys($_POST, array_flip($required_fields)));
```

This will create local variables for each of the variables named in `$required_fields` only if it exists in the $_POST array. Otherwise, the variable will be undefined.

[array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)
[array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)
[extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score -2):

You can also use

```
eval("$".$fieldname."='".$_POST["fieldname"]."';");
```

Comment: why invoke a new PHP interpreter?

Comment: This is another example of how the issue can be solved. Although is also dangerous if the values aren't validated properly.
The final result is same as your given solution.