# Multiple products filter from mysql data using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter and display data from mysql using PHP. Below are my input filters.

```
<form id="search_form">
            <div class="well">
                <h4 class="text-info">Search by Size</h4>
                <input value="32" class="sort_rang" name="size[]" value="New" type="checkbox"> 32
                <input value="36" class="sort_rang" name="size[]" value="fashion" type="checkbox"> 36
                <input value="38" class="sort_rang" name="size[]" value="New" type="checkbox"> 38
            </div>
            
            <div class="well">
                <h4 class="text-info">Search by price</h4>
                <input value="950" class="sort_rangn" name="price[]" value="New" type="checkbox"> 950
                <input value="1024" class="sort_rangn" name="price[]" value="fashion" type="checkbox"> 1024
                <input value="500" class="sort_rangn" name="price[]" value="New" type="checkbox"> 500
            </div>
          </form>
```

Now we have two filters size and price both are taken in array and search in mysql.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products";
    extract($_POST);
            
    if(isset($size)) 
        $sql.=" WHERE size IN (".implode(',', $size).")";

    if(isset($price))
        
        $sql.=" WHERE (price IN (".implode(',', $price)."))";
        
    $all_row=$db->query($sql);
```

It's working fine but only one condition is working - either size or price and I am using one table name -products.

Comment: have you checked that both `size` and `price` are set at the same time?

Comment: i tried AND and OR but not worked, i think its placed in wrong place

Comment: You didn't get my point. okay tell me , Did you get any error?

Comment: Your inputs have two values each, an int and a string, you should remove the string value.

Comment: In case anyone sees this question, never use extract() on untrusted data such as user inputs ($_GET, $_POST etc), it's insecure.  See here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907358/is-using-extract-post-insecure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code snippet:

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products";
    extract($_POST);

    if(isset($size) && isset($price))
        $sql.=" WHERE size IN (".implode(',', $size).") OR price IN (".implode(',', $price).")"; 
    else if(isset($size)) 
        $sql.=" WHERE size IN (".implode(',', $size).")";

    else if(isset($price))

        $sql.=" WHERE (price IN (".implode(',', $price)."))";

    $all_row=$db->query($sql);
```

The filtering succeeds either for size or price. If you want to match both of them use `AND` instead of `OR` in the first `if` statement

**Note:** In your code if both variables are set in a case then you will get syntax error. Here comes the use of `IF ELSEIF` chain.

Suppose both `$price` and `$size` variables are set. Then your `$sql` variable will be affected by both of the `IF` statements. Then your final generated `query` will have two where clauses which will generate an error for bad syntax. Your generated query will more or less look like below:

`SELECT .... WHERE size IN (....) WHERE price IN (...) ...` (***BAD SYNTAX***)

Comment: is the this a correct way? i dont know but no error its working fine. grate thank you.

Comment: i dont understand you note

Comment: Since any one of the conditions should be active at any given time so `IF ELSE IF` chain comes into use.

Comment: and if i want to add one more condiation like date range. between 5 march to 15th march

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107458/discussion-between-asesha-george-and-1000111).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products";
extract($_POST);

if(isset($size) && isset($price))
    $sql.=" WHERE size IN (".implode(',', $size).") AND price IN (".implode(',', $price).")"; 
else if(isset($size)) 
    $sql.=" WHERE size IN (".implode(',', $size).")";

else if(isset($price))

    $sql.=" WHERE (price IN (".implode(',', $price)."))";

$all_row=$db->query($sql);
```

Use this code this is working for me .