Is it possible to get POST data without writting $_POST[]?
Is it possible to get POST data by just writing the POST variable name like $post_var_name instead of writing $_POST["post_var_name"]? I recently ran into this kind of code, I tried wrapping the variable name with $_POST[], making it become $_POST["post_var_name"] and it worked, I can get the POST data. However, there are a lot of code like this in the project, if I have to change all of them, it would be a terrible nightmare. Need help, thanks!

Old code based on register_globals?

You can emulate it with extract(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907358/is-using-extract-post-insecure

If you have a lot of scripts, consider using an auto-prepend to execute extract() automatically.

@Olivier you're right! an old feature deprecated after PHP 5.3. After I turned on register_globals configuration options, this old project worked. Would you mind post it as answer and let me accept it? This saved me.
